# Is Hadoop a collection of Data Servers or a software that manages Databases?

Tags: hadoop

I have watched hundreds of videos and red hundreds of articles. but they are all so complicated? Why people cant clearly make a good introduction of what is something before breaking it down? What the hell is Hadoop? I get it is some kind of file distributing system, it has cool features like high performance, HDFS, YARN, MapReduce , Hadoop Common bla bla. Please someone, tell me what is it? is it a software like Visual Studio, Anaconda Navigator, Android Studio or what? or is it a huge company that has thousands of data servers where you can upload your company's data and manage it perfectly over there? Why these videos on YouTube say that Hadoop is storage efficient? does it mean you use Hadoop's data servers and they save your data efficiently? I am absolutely sure that I am not the only one who asks these questions when they are watching these videos on YouTube.
Thanks In advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is an ecosystem, means consist of several software which can work together in a distributed mode.

Three main software inside Hadoop which provided as service are : HDFS, YARN, MapReduce.

HDFS is a distributed file system. It means HDFS is a filesystem something like our PC filesystem (NTFS, FAT32, EXT4, etc.). The main goal of a file system is management of files. each file in a file system consist of blocks (consider a file is divided to chunks). our local filesystem remain these block on one machine but HDFS split(and distribute) them on several machine.

YARN is a resource manager like our resource manager inside our OS, but it manages resource from several machines. When you run an application (i.e. Notepad) inside your PC, your OS gives your application CPU core (when needed) and  Memory. In Yarn when you submit and application it gives your application CPU core (when needed) and  Memory on all machines and your application must know how to work in distributed mode.

MapReduce help you to write programs in distributed mode and you don't need know how to write your application in distributed mode. MapReduce is something like a programming language plus a compiler which Yarn can know how to run its program.

Answer (score 0):

One day google decided to introduce a distributed file server,
and named it Google File System, or GFS.
This idea has published in 2003 a paper: [https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en/ir/archive/gfs-sosp2003.pdf]

At the same time, Doug Cutting, the creator of Apache Lucene, were working on apache Nutch, this paper helped them to implement a nice distributed file system named NDFS or Nutch Distributed File System.

The, Nutch were able to split files in multiple blocks and store them in multiple servers and replicate them to preserver data reliability.
But this data needs to be processed, and you can simply fetch terabytes of data on a single machine and process them.
in 2004, Google again came with a great idea named Map Reduce.
[http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html]

with Map Reduce, you can put your data processing codes near your data blocks, process them locally (map phase) then gather results and sum them up (reduce phase).

now Nutch has both ndfs and map reduce.

quoting from the book, Hadoop definitive guide by Tom White:

> NDFS and the MapReduce
> implementation in Nutch were applicable beyond the realm of search,
> and in February 2006 they moved out of Nutch to form an independent
> subproject of Lucene called Hadoop.

this is story of hadoop.
but now, other tools has came along to co-work with Hadoop
like Apache Hive which helps us to run SQL like queries on Big and distributed data on Hadoop File System (now named HDFS).
or Apache Pig that uses a high level language to run complex analysis on Hadoop stored files using map reduce framework.
there is much other tools like Hbase, Spark, Flume, Sqoop, Crunch, etc.
we dont call them Hadoop! but they live in a Hadoop centered ecosystem.
so we call this community, Hadoop Ecosystem.

Its better if you start reading  the book: Hadoop definitive guide by Tom White
instead of reading multiple blog posts and YouTube videos.